# how to place yii2 form error in title of anchor tag

Tags: php, yii, yii2, yii2-advanced-app, yii2-validation

how to place yii2 form error in title of anchor tag

This is my code

```
$form = ActiveForm::begin([
    'id' => 'login-form',
    'options' => ['class' => 'form-horizontal'],
    'fieldConfig' => [
        'template' => '
            {label}
            <div class="error-block">
                <a href="#" title="{error}">error</a>
            </div>
            {input}
            ',
        'errorOptions' => ['tag' => null]
    ],
]);
```

I want to add error in title of anchor tag in YII2

```
<a href="#" title="{error}">error</a>
```

Comment: this code is correct, I think your problem is in your model rules, please check it

Comment: I think this will not work. I checked the source of Yii2 and seems that `{error}` by default uses `\yii\helpers\BaseHtml::error()` which generates a HTML markup instead of regular string...

Answer (score 0):

You need to display the error text inside the anchor tags `title` attribute, and using the `template` option wont help you achieve it automatically.

A few things in your approach.

- You are specifying the `"tag"=>null` under the `errorOptions` which wont create the default html `<p class="help-block help-block-error"></p>`.
- Even if you specify the tag as `div` or `span` even then it will break the HTML as the attribute title has double quotes `<a href="#" title="{error}">error</a>` and the tag created will also have double quotes `<div class="help-block help-block-error"></div>`.
- Then if you change the `<a href="#" title="{error}">error</a>` to `<a href="#" title=\'{error}\'>error</a>` to fix the broken `HTML` the javascript wont be able to detect the element.

So then the event `afterValidateAttribute` will come to your rescue which is triggered after validating the whole form and each attribute.

> The signature of the event handler should be:
>
> `function (event, attribute, messages)`
>
> where
>
> - `event`: an Event object.
> - `attribute`: the attribute being validated. Please refer to `attributeDefaults` for the structure of this parameter.
> - `messages`: an array to which you can add additional validation error messages for the specified attribute.

Now change the `template` under the `fieldConfig` to the following and remove the `{error}` from the template and the `errorOptions`, as it is not needed and just keep you custom error element inside the template.

```
'fieldConfig' => [
    'template' => '
        {label}
        <div class="error-block">
            <a href="#" title="">error</a>
        </div>
        {input}
        ',
],
```

Now add the below javascript at the top of your view where you are rendering the form.

```
$js = <<< JS
$("#login-form").on(
    'afterValidateAttribute',
    function (event,attribute,messages) {
        let input=attribute.input;
        $(input).siblings('.error-block').find('a').attr('title',messages.join(','));
    }
);
JS;
$this->registerJs($js, \yii\web\View::POS_READY);
```

Now if you `focus` out of the fields or hit the submit button you will see the error messages being populated in the `title` attribute of the `a` tag.