# How to customize validation error message to display on tooltip in Yii2?

Tags: php, yii2, tooltip, custom-errors, yii2-validation

I am using ActiveForm of yii2 and I want to customize the validation errors. I want to display errors on tooltip.

This is my form

```
<?= $form = ActiveForm::begin(['id' => 'login-form','method'=>'post']); ?>
    <?= 
        $form->field($model, 'email')
            ->textInput([
                'class'=>'form-control login_email',
                'placeholder'=>'Email'
                /*'onfocus'=>"this.value = '';",
                "onblur"=>"if (this.value == '') {
                    this.value = 'Email';
                }"*/
            ])
            ->label(false);
    ?>
    <?= 
        $form->field($model, 'password')
            ->passwordInput([
                'class'=>'form-control',
                'placeholder'=>'Password'
            ])
            ->label(false);
    ?>
    <input type="text" name="hidden" value="login" hidden="true">
    <p class="forgot">
        <a href="<?= Yii::$app->urlManager->createUrl(['site/request-password-reset']); ?>">
            Forgot Password?
        </a>
    </p>

    <div class="form-group">
        <?= Html::submitButton('Log In', ['class' => 'sign-in','name' => 'login-button']) ?>
    </div>
<?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
```

Please tell me if anyone has idea about this.

Comment: I have answered another question asked previously where the error needed to be displayed inside the `title` attribute of the `anchor` and it addresses the same thing you are asking as the tooltip works with the title too, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53607230/how-to-place-yii2-form-error-in-title-of-anchor-tag/53621680#53621680) if it helps you out

Answer (score 0):

Update error message in form template like below

```
  $form = ActiveForm::begin([
  'id' => 'login-form',
  'options' => ['enctype' => 'multipart/form-data'],
   'fieldConfig' => ['template' => "<div class=\"input-cover\"><div class=\"tooltip\">{error}</div>\n{label}\n{input}</div>",
  'inputOptions' => ['class' => 'input-control'],
                    ],
          ]);
```

Comment: No it's not working. Are you having any css on class input-cover and tooltip?

Comment: .tooltip .help-block {
    position: absolute;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 6px 8px;
    width: 150px;
    top: 0px;
    right: -180px;
    background: rgba(213,16,24,0.9);
    border: 1px solid #d51018;
    border-radius: 6px;
    z-index: 999;
}

Comment: .input-cover {
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}